# "daily limit exceeded" when using Google custom search API

Tags: python, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

I wanna crawl 200 results for about 2000 queries but it gives me a "daily limit exceeded" error.

I want to confirm how many results can we crawl per day. Is there any solution that can solve this problem? Or the only way is to crawl a small part of queries each day...?

My code to crawl google is as follow:

```
def crawl(query_list):
    http = httplib2.Http()

    # Construct the service object for the interacting with the CustomSearch API.
    service = discovery.build('customsearch', 'v1',  developerKey='my api key', http=http)

    res_list = []
    for query in query_list:
        json_res = service.cse().list(q = query, cx = 'my search engine id', num = 200,).execute()
        res_list.append(json_res)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does the license say? (you agreed to one to get your developer key)

Comment: sorry but I'm very new to google api...where can I see the license? I only know I use the free "custom search engine" instead of "google site search". Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to this [post](http://dazdaztech.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/using-google-custom-search-api-from-the-command-line/):

> The first 100 queries per day are free. Any more, then you have to pay
>   $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day, just enable
>   billing to do so. Each query returns a maximum of 10 results, so you
>   can retrieve 1000 URL’s from your search per day for free.